# Como unir dos columnas en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un sp procedure donde me registra el sueldo historico en cierto mes . Lo que necesito es unir eso dos sueldos en una sola columna.

este es mi codigo

```
select distinct(Personal.NombrePersonal) as [Colaborador],
Personal.FechaIngreso,
SueldoHistorico.fechainicio as[Sueldo Historico],
case
 when month(fechainicio)=1 and year(Personal.FechaIngreso)<=2019
  then SueldoHistorico.sueldo else 0 end as Enero,
case
 when month(fechainicio)=2 and year(Personal.FechaIngreso)<=2019 then SueldoHistorico.sueldo
  else 0 end as Febrero,
case 
when month(fechainicio)=3 and year(Personal.FechaIngreso)<=2019 then SueldoHistorico.sueldo
 else 0 end as Marzo,
case
 when month(fechainicio)=4 and year(Personal.FechaIngreso)<=2019 then SueldoHistorico.sueldo 
 else 0 end as Abril
 from SueldoHistorico inner join Personal on SueldoHistorico.personal_id=Personal.PersonalID
 where SueldoHistorico.fechainicio between '2019-01-01' and '2019-04-30' group by Personal.NombrePersonal,Personal.FechaIngreso,SueldoHistorico.sueldo,SueldoHistorico.fechainicio
```

Este es el resultado de mi select.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿En una sola columna o una sola fila?

Comment: ¿Realmente sabes lo que quieres? ¿qué significa el sueldo histórico? ¿quieres una columna con el acumulado? ¿No es lo que se muestra ya en los meses? Aunque hayas creído que sí, tu consulta está muy lejos de ser clara para poder ser respondida

Comment: Seria muy bueno que aclares si deseas mostrar los datos en una sola fila o una sola columna

Comment: Lo que deseo es que un colaborador tenga todos los sueldos en uno solo y luego sumar todos los sueldos.